# Question mark shown instead of citation using harvard

Tags: natbib, harvard-style, cite-package

I am getting `[?]` when citing using `harvard`. If I use `\citeasnoun` I get the citation. How do I solve this problem. I am using TeXnicCenter with MikTeX 2.9 and installed the `harvard` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float,epsfig}
\usepackage{pifont,epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
%\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[sort]{cite}
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\parindent=0pt                  % Do not indent paragraphs
\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.8in}
\begin{document}
------
 \bibliographystyle{agsm}
 \bibliography{ref}
%\input{bio_2}
\end{document}
```

When I use `natbib` I get it correct. I also wish to replace `&` with `and` when I use `\citet` in `natbib`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want sorted citations and therefore load both the `harvard` and `cite` packages, but apparently the latter is not compatible with the former. I suggest that you load just `natbib` with its `sort` option, which emulates the `sort` option of `cite` .

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% Variant A: Doesn't work
% \usepackage{harvard}
% \usepackage[sort]{cite}

% Variant B: Works
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citep{B02,A01}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't load both the `harvard` and the `cite` packages (or, for that matter, both the `natbib` and the `cite` packages). The `cite` package is designed for numeric-style citations, whereas the `harvard` and `natbib` packages are meant mainly for authoryear-style citations. (OK, the `natbib` package *can* be used for numeric-style citations *if* it is invoked with the `numbers` option.)

If you're using the `agsm` bibliography style, which comes with the `harvard` package but can be along with `natbib` as well, you can get the conjunction between authors' names to be displayed as `and` instead of as `&` by issuing the command

```
\def\harvardand{and}  % default: "&"
```

after loading either the `harvard` or the `natbib` package.